# Is it possible to pass a statement with a comma into a boost test macro?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, boost

As I wanted to unit-test a small class I wrote with boost::test, I discovered that the boost MACRO to CHECK/REQUIRE/.... cannot be use directly if the statement you pass contain a ','.

The following example doesn't compile as the preprocessor reports that `macro "BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1`

```
BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW({cache_map<int, int> test1(3);});
```

Just to confirm it comes from the comma we use to separate the template parameters, I used the following and it compiled without issue.

```
BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW({string test1("test");});
```

**A work-around is to use a `typedef`alias** instead of the explicit type but have you another idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With simple expressions, the solution is to put the macro argument in parentheses, such as

```
BOOST_CHECK((std::is_same<int, int>::value));
```

However, since you have a block there, that route is not open to you (unless you don't care about portability and your compiler accepts it; gcc does, for example). Knowing that expressions are fine, though, we can trick our way out of the predicament with lambdas:

```
BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW(([]{cache_map<int, int> test1(3);}()));
```

Whether you think this is prettier than type aliases is up to you, though.

Comment: But as usual even if that works fine with GCC, VS'08 doesn't deal with that :)

Comment: Alas, Visual Studio 2008 does not support C++11 at all. Support for lambdas was introduced in VS 2010, I believe (full support for C++11 has yet to come to Visual Studio).

Comment: Putting the first argument in parenthesis solved my problem which was testing if a specific exception was being thrown in a constructor with multiple arguments which were comma-separated. Before stumbling on this question through google I was considering including a std::initializer_list constructor as a workaround, but that would be very inconvenient even if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is simple compared to the compiler, and doesn't have any knowledge of the actual text it preprocesses (it can be used for any kind of text-file, not only C or C++ source files). That means it just uses the comma as an argument separator in macro invocations, and you can't pass macro arguments containing commas.

One way to work around your specific issue is, as you state, to use type-aliases.